# Как реализована полоса прокрутки на этом сайте ?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом реализована красивая полоса прокрутки на этом сайте: [тык-тык](https://www.allfordj.ru/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это в главном меню, при наведении на пункт "Магазин".

В коде никаких элементов, или псевдоэлементов, никаких стилей, которые могли бы установить этот вертикальный скролл нету..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если сайт по ширине сжать, горизонтальный скролл появляется тоже такой стилизованный..

Что за библиотека такая, которая делает такой скролл без лишних элементов в коде?

Comment: https://yraaa.ru/scripts/stilizatsiya-polosyi-prokrutki-s-pomoschyu-css

Comment: Стили как раз очень даже есть (описаны по ссылке выше), просто DevTools хрома их не показывает и надо смотреть напрямую в CSS-файле

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:1000px"></div>
```

Ну например как-то так.

Но данное решение (как и на сайте примера) работает только в хром.

Чтобы работало во всех браузерах необходимо использовать JS ([например](https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar))